# C# XML How to retrive innerText of field by attribute?

Tags: c#, xml, xml-parsing

Here is the XML sample:

```
  <?xml version="1.0" ?> 
  <XMLScreen xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <CX>80</CX> 
  <CY>24</CY> 
  <Formatted>true</Formatted> 
  <Field>
  <Location position="1" left="1" top="0" length="69" /> 
  <Attributes Base="226" Protected="false" FieldType="High" /> 
  *SDC SCHEDULING CATEGORY UPDATE 
  </Field>
  </XMLScreen>
```

I want to retrive the Inner text of each field based on its `Location position`.

What I have so far is:

```
  XmlDocument xmlDoc = new XmlDocument();
  xmlDoc.LoadXml(myEm.CurrentScreenXML.GetXMLText());
  XmlNodeList fields = xmlDoc.GetElementsByTagName("Field");

  MessageBox.Show("Field spot: " + i + " Contains: " + fields[i].InnerText);
```

And I want to be able to just extract the inner text of the field by passing in a number of the location position. So if I say `foo[i]` I want to be able to get the innertext

> *SDC SCHEDULING CATEGORY UPDATE

Answer (score 0):

Something like that, with XDocument instead of XmlDocument (well, if you're not in .net 3.5 or higher, we'll have a problem).

```
private string GetTextByLocationId(XDocument document, int id)
{
     var field = document.Descendants("Field").FirstOrDefault(m => m.Element("Location").Attribute("position").Value == id.ToString());
     if (field == null) return null;
     return field.Value;
}
```

and usage

```
var xDocument = XDocument.Load(<pathToXmlFile or XmlReader or string or ...>);
var result = GetTextByLocationId(xDocument, 1);
```

**EDIT**

or if you want a dictionary with :key = position / value = text

```
private static Dictionary<int, string> ParseLocationAndText(XDocument document)
        {
            var fields = document.Descendants("Field");
            return fields.ToDictionary(
                 f => Convert.ToInt32(f.Element("Location").Attribute("position").Value),
                 f => f.Value);
        }
```

Comment: How do I load an XDocument? Is it just an XML doc?

Comment: @CodingIsAwesome as shown in code, it might be a file, a XmlReader, a string : see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/system.xml.linq.xdocument.load%28v=vs.100%29

Comment: @CodingIsAwesome XDocument is in System.Xml.Linq

Comment: You can clean that up a lot by casting to the appropriate type, rather than parsing.

Answer (score 0):

You should use a xpath search query :

```
  XmlDocument xmlDoc = new XmlDocument();
  xmlDoc.LoadXml(xml);
  int nodeId = 4;
  XmlNode node = xmlDoc.SelectSingleNode(String.Format(@"//Location[@position='{0}']", nodeId));
  if (node != null)
  {
      String field = node.ParentNode.InnerText;
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try,

```
XElement root = XElement.Parse(myEm.CurrentScreenXML.GetXMLText());
XElement field = root.XPathSelectElement(
                    string.Format("Field[Location/@position='{0}']", 1));
string text = field.Value;
```

You will need to use the following using to use XPath with XElements.

```
using System.Xml.XPath;
```